# yum list available showing packages, but yum update not installing those packages....These rpms are not present

Tags: yum

```
# yum list available
Available Packages
python-deltarpm.x86_64                                                       3.5-0.5.20090913git.el6                                                       PATCHUPDATEKT
samba-client.x86_64                                                          3.5.10-114.el6                                                                PATCHUPDATEKT
samba-winbind.x86_64                                                         3.5.10-114.el6                                                                PATCHUPDATEKT
vsftpd.x86_64                                                                2.2.2-6.el6_0.1                                                               PATCHUPDATEKT
#

# yum update
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
#

# rpm -qa  | grep -i python-deltarpm
#
#rpm -qa  | grep -i samba-client
#
#rpm -qa  | grep -i samba-winbind
samba-winbind-clients-3.5.10-114.el6.x86_64
#
```

Answer (score 1):

`yum available` shows all available packages in all repositories.
It indicates not only updates.

I do not know the repository `PATCHUPDATEKT`, but it does not look like you have an update for an installed package. Please check with `yum list installed | grep -e python-deltarpm`.

If you really need one of these packages, you can try to install it. But please consider In this case, the dependencies must be satisfied.

Comment: PATCHUPDATEKT is a test repository which i created  for testing yum update .

Comment: Would like to know whther yum update will not install new packages . Will it only update the installed packages  ? Is there any way to install new packages and update the old ones from a repository using yum update command ?

Comment: If samba-client is not installed, yum will ignore it during an update. So yes it will only update installed packages.

How yum should know what new packages you want to install? You have a small repository, but normaly it's very big.